# Wpf - Edit Resource in run time

Tags: wpf, resources, styles

I have this xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="root">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="btnStyle">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource btnStyle}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and my question is how can I change the btnStyle setter value to Red from code behind?

Answer (score 1):

This is the direct answer to your question:

```
var style = (Style) this.root.findResource("btnStyle");
style.Setters.Item[0].Value = Brushes.Red;
```

But what are you trying to accomplish exactly?